# SMTP JS Not Working With No Errors (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, email, smtp

SMTP JS has stopped working for me on my signup page on my website. My email server is Elastic Email. There are no signs of any SMTP JS data in my activity inbox.

Below is my email sending javaScript the idea is when the variable *studentSignup* is = to 1 Than this code will run:

```
       if (signupStudents === 1) {
    
        var send = function() {
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Password : "9401A8928B5701CCC4891E79E0CBF1B61C8582CA91F8769DC1A056AF9A85393F3B8A8AEA34C86A198C54EC677A3440B0",
    To : 'ektechworld@gmail.com',
    From : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Subject : "New Intermdite Signup",
    Body : "Parent Name " + document.getElementById ("parent-name"),
}).then(
    window.location.replace("/sucuss.html"),
);
};

}
```

Otherwise this will happen:

```
else {
    var send = function() {
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Password : "CBFAA2D72FF7E206C34F23FA8A131EA2D275",
    To : 'ektechworld@gmail.com',
    From : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Subject : "New Intermdite Signup",
    Body : "Parent Name " + document.getElementById ("parent-name") + "yay"
}).then(
    window.location.replace("/sucuss.html"),
);
};
}
```

You can see all the website code in the code snippet.

```js
 var newStudentBtn = document.getElementById ("new-student");
        var students = document.getElementById ("students");
        var signupStudents = 1;
        var cost = document.getElementById ("cost");
        var confirmedStudents = "'test'"
        var studentNamesCode;
        
        let ids = new Object ();
        ids.idNames = "";
        ids.getInfo = function () {
            return this.idNames;
        };


        
        var newStudentBtnOnClick = function () {
            signupStudents++;
            let newStudent = document.createElement ("input");
            newStudent.placeholder="Type your child's first and last name here";
            newStudent.id = "signup-students-input" + signupStudents;
            
            let newStudentHeading = document.createElement ("h3");
            let studentNewLine = document.createElement ("br");
            newStudentHeading.innerHTML = "Child (" + signupStudents + ") First and Last Name";
            students.appendChild (newStudentHeading)
            students.appendChild (newStudent);
            
            cost.innerHTML = signupStudents*39
            if (signupStudents > 2) {
            ids.idNames += "+  'Student(' + signupStudents + ')' + document.getElementById ('" + newStudent.id + "').value ";
            }
            else {
                ids.idNames += "confirmedStudents + document.getElementById ('" + newStudent.id + "').value ";
            }

            studentNamesCode = eval(ids.getInfo());
           
            console.log (ids.getInfo())
            console.log (studentNamesCode) 

            
        };

        newStudentBtn.addEventListener ("click", newStudentBtnOnClick);

      

       if (signupStudents === 1) {
    
        var send = function() {
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Password : "9401A8928B5701CCC4891E79E0CBF1B61C8582CA91F8769DC1A056AF9A85393F3B8A8AEA34C86A198C54EC677A3440B0",
    To : 'ektechworld@gmail.com',
    From : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Subject : "New Intermdite Signup",
    Body : "Parent Name " + document.getElementById ("parent-name"),
}).then(
    window.location.replace("/sucuss.html"),
);
};

}

else {
    var send = function() {
    Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
    Username : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Password : "CBFAA2D72FF7E206C34F23FA8A131EA2D275",
    To : 'ektechworld@gmail.com',
    From : "ektechworld@gmail.com",
    Subject : "New Intermdite Signup",
    Body : "Parent Name " + document.getElementById ("parent-name") + "yay"
}).then(
    window.location.replace("/sucuss.html"),
);
};
}
```

```html
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img_2.jpg" class="nav-img"></a>
            <div class="nav-options">
                <button class="nav-option">About Us</button>
                <button class="nav-option">Classes</button>
                <button class="nav-option">Contact Us</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>Signup for the Intermedite Class</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info-content">
        <div class="diveder"><h2>Please fill out the form</h2></div>
       
        <div class="info-content-blocks">
            <form onsubmit="send(); reset(); return false;">
                <div id="students">
            <h3>Parent First and Last Name</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your first and last name here" required id="parent-name">
            <h3>Child (1) First and Last Name</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your child's first and last name here" required class="student-names">
        </div>
            
        <br><br><button class="standard-button" id="new-student" type="button">New Student</button><br><br>
            <h3>Parent Email Address</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your email address here" required>
            <h3>Parent Phone Number (For Emgerency Contact Only)</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your phone number here" required>
            <p>Please pay $<span id="cost">39</span> cash after your childs first class.</p>
            <button class="standard-button" type="submit">Enroll</button>

</form>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Email here. I confirm that on Friday the problem was solved on our end so everything should be working well now. Please be informed that this problem may occur again in the future as it is related to how smtpjs library works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this issue. I firstly tried to regenerate my secure token via https://smtpjs.com/ but received this error:

'Port 2525 on smtp.elasticemail.com is not open'

I then reached out to ElasticEmail support and they responded:

"Please be informed that we've received several similar reports. It seems that there is an issue with SmtpJS. Our Developers are looking into this. We will get back to you as soon as possible. Thank you for your patience."

So it would seem that it may be an issue on their end.

Comment: I received a response from ElasticEmail today that the issue is resolved. I tested my app and it is now functional.